# Groovy NodeBuilder: how to pass closures around

Tags: xml, groovy

I apologize in advance for the newbie question, but here it is. Let's say I am trying to generate markup using Groovy's `NodeBuilder`. I'd like to write something like the following:

```
nodes = { 
  'element'(key:'value')
  'element'(blah:'123') 
}
def createMarkup(additionalElements) {    
  def result = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder().root{
    someElement(){
      element(y: 'uh oh')  
      additionalElements() // does not work this way!
      element(z: 'yeah')
    }
  }
}

createMarkup(nodes)
```

which results in:

```
<root>
  <someElement>
    <element y='uh oh' />
    <element z='yeah' />
  </someElement>
</root>
```

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is to have one (or more) externally defined closure(s) that I can pass to my `createMarkup()` and then stick at the right level in the tree, i.e., I'd like it to generate this:

```
<root>
  <someElement>
    <element y='uh oh' />
    <element key='value' />
    <element blah='123' />
    <element z='yeah' />
  </someElement>
</root>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
nodes = { builder ->
  builder.element(key:'value')
  builder.element(blah:'123') 
}    

def createMarkup(additionalElements) {    
  def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()
  def result = builder.root{
    someElement(){
      element(y: 'uh oh')  
      additionalElements(builder)
      element(z: 'yeah')
    }
  }
}

createMarkup(nodes)
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `additionalElements` is closure. To execute it you should write:

```
additionalElements()
```

instead of:

```
additionalElements
```